# OpenCV library in Tomcat(8.5.32) Server unable to execute

Tags: java, opencv, error-handling, tesseract, tomcat8

Facing issue while image processing code setup. In spite of doing all code changes and different approaches facing the issue.

Libraries used – OpenCV – 3.4.2
Jars Used – opencv-3.4.2-0
tess4j-3.4.8

Lines added in pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openpnp/opencv -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2-0</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.tess4j/tess4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

Steps for OpenCV installation :

1. Download opencv.exe from the official site’
2. Run opencv.exe, it will create an opencv folder
3. We have now the opencv library available which we can use for eclipse.

Steps for Tesseract installation :

1. Download tess4j.zip file from the official link
2. Extract the zip folder after download
3. Provide the path of the tess4j folder

Following are the steps which we have performed for the setup in eclipse :

1. We have added native library by providing path to openCV library from build path settings
2. We downloaded tesseract for image reading.
3. We provided the path to the Tesseraact in the code
4. We have used System.loadlibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME) and openCv.loadLocally() for loading the library.

Then we have made the WAR export for deployment
There has been no changes or setup in apache tomcat

For loading the libraries in Tomcat we have to provide some setup here :-
Now for the new code we have used, Load Library static class in the code (as solutions stated on stack overflow)
In here System.loadLibrary is not working
We had to use System.load along with  hardcoded path which is resulting in internal error

We have used  System.load – 2 time in the static class out of which the when the 1st one is giving -std error -bad allocation
As there are 2 paths in opencv-
This is the 1st one
System.load("C:\Users\Downloads\opencv\build\bin\opencv_java342.dll");

and the 2nd one is giving the assertion error based on which one is kept above
This is the 2nd one
System.load("C:\User\Downloads\opencv\build\java\x64\opencv_java3412.dll");

The code is executing till mid-way and then getting out and  till now not yet code has reached till tesseract.

```
Here is the code for the same :

    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    
    import org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger;
    import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
    import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
    import org.opencv.core.Core;
    import org.opencv.core.CvException;
    import org.opencv.core.Mat;
    import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
    import org.opencv.core.Rect;
    import org.opencv.core.Size;
    import org.opencv.highgui.HighGui;
    import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
    import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
    
    import net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract;
    import nu.pattern.OpenCV;
    
    public class ReadImageBox {
            
        public String readDataFromImage(String imageToReadPath,String tesseractPath) 
        {
    
            String result = "";
            try {
                String i = Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME;
                System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
                
                logger.info("Img to read "+imageToReadPath);
                String imagePath =imageToReadPath; // bufferNameOfImagePath = "";
                logger.info(imagePath);
            
    
                        /*
                         * The class Mat represents an n-dimensional dense numerical single-channel or
                         * multi-channel array. It can be used to store real or complex-valued vectors
                         * and matrices, grayscale or color images, voxel volumes, vector fields, point
                         * clouds, tensors, histograms (though, very high-dimensional histograms may be
                         * better stored in a SparseMat ).
                         */
                        logger.info("imagepath::"+imagePath);
    
                         OpenCV.loadLocally();
                        
                        logger.info("imagepath::"+imagePath);
                        //logger.info("Library Information"+Core.getBuildInformation());
    
                        logger.info("imagepath::"+imagePath);
                        Mat source = Imgcodecs.imread(imagePath);
    
                        logger.info("Source image "+source);
                        String directoryPath = imagePath.substring(0,imagePath.lastIndexOf('/'));
                
                        
                        logger.info("Going for Image Processing :" + directoryPath);
                        
                        // calling image processing here to process the data from it
                        result = updateImage(100,20,10,3,3,2,source, directoryPath,tesseractPath);  
                        
                        logger.info("Data read "+result);
        return result;
            }
            catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError error) {
                // Output expected UnsatisfiedLinkErrors.
                logger.error(error);
            } 
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                logger.error(exception);
            }
            return result;
        }
    
        public static String updateImage(int boxSize, int horizontalRemoval, int verticalRemoval, int gaussianBlur,
                int denoisingClosing, int denoisingOpening, Mat source, String tempDirectoryPath,String tesseractPath) throws Exception{
    
            // Tesseract Object
            logger.info("Tesseract Path :"+tesseractPath);
            Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();
            tesseract.setDatapath(tesseractPath);
    
            // Creating the empty destination matrix for further processing
            Mat grayScaleImage = new Mat();``
            Mat gaussianBlurImage = new Mat();
            Mat thresholdImage = new Mat();
            Mat morph = new Mat();
            Mat morphAfterOpreation = new Mat();
            Mat dilate = new Mat();
            Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    
            logger.info("Image type"+source.type());
            
            // Converting the image to gray scale and saving it in the grayScaleImage matrix
            Imgproc.cvtColor(source, grayScaleImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
            //Imgproc.cvtColor(source, grayScaleImage, 0);
            
            
            // Applying Gaussain Blur
            logger.info("source image "+source);
            
            Imgproc.GaussianBlur(grayScaleImage, gaussianBlurImage, new org.opencv.core.Size(gaussianBlur, gaussianBlur),
                    0);
    
            // OTSU threshold
            Imgproc.threshold(gaussianBlurImage, thresholdImage, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU | Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    
            logger.info("Threshold image "+gaussianBlur);
            
            // remove the lines of any table inside the invoice
            Mat horizontal = thresholdImage.clone();
            Mat vertical = thresholdImage.clone();
    
            int horizontal_size = horizontal.cols() / 30;
            if(horizontal_size%2==0)
                horizontal_size+=1;
    
            // showWaitDestroy("Horizontal Lines Detected", horizontal);
    
            Mat horizontalStructure = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT,
                    new org.opencv.core.Size(horizontal_size, 1));
            Imgproc.erode(horizontal, horizontal, horizontalStructure);
            Imgproc.dilate(horizontal, horizontal, horizontalStructure);
    
            int vertical_size = vertical.rows() / 30;
            if(vertical_size%2==0)
                vertical_size+=1;
    
            // Create structure element for extracting vertical lines through morphology
            // operations
            Mat verticalStructure = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT,
                    new org.opencv.core.Size(1, vertical_size));
    
            // Apply morphology operations
            Imgproc.erode(vertical, vertical, verticalStructure);
            Imgproc.dilate(vertical, vertical, verticalStructure);
    
            Core.absdiff(thresholdImage, horizontal, thresholdImage);
            Core.absdiff(thresholdImage, vertical, thresholdImage);
    
            logger.info("Vertical Structure "+verticalStructure);
            
    
            
            Mat newImageFortest = thresholdImage;
            
            
            logger.info("Threshold image "+thresholdImage);
            // applying Closing operation
            Imgproc.morphologyEx(thresholdImage, morph, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(
                    Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(denoisingClosing, denoisingClosing)));
    
            
            logger.info("Morph image "+morph);
            
            // applying Opening operation
            Imgproc.morphologyEx(morph, morphAfterOpreation, Imgproc.MORPH_OPEN, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(
                    Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(denoisingOpening, denoisingOpening)));
    
            
            logger.info("Morph After operation image "+morphAfterOpreation);
            // Applying dilation on the threshold image to create bounding box edges
            Imgproc.dilate(morphAfterOpreation, dilate,
                    Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(boxSize, boxSize)));
    
            
            logger.info("Dilate image "+dilate);
            
            // creating string buffer object
            String text = "";
            
            try
            {
            
            // finding contours
            List<MatOfPoint> contourList = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>(); // A list to store all the contours
    
            // finding contours
            Imgproc.findContours(dilate, contourList, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    
            logger.info("Contour List "+contourList);
            
            
            // Creating a copy of the image
            //Mat copyOfImage = source;
            Mat copyOfImage = newImageFortest;
            
            logger.info("Copy of Image "+copyOfImage);
            
            // Rectangle for cropping
            Rect rectCrop = new Rect();
    
            logger.info("Rectangle Crop New Object "+rectCrop);
    
            // loop through the identified contours and crop them from the image to feed
            // into Tesseract-OCR
    
            for (int i = 0; i < contourList.size(); i++) {
                // getting bound rectangle
                rectCrop = Imgproc.boundingRect(contourList.get(i));
    
                logger.info("Rectangle cropped"+rectCrop);
                
                // cropping Image
                Mat croppedImage = copyOfImage.submat(rectCrop.y, rectCrop.y + rectCrop.height, rectCrop.x,
                        rectCrop.x + rectCrop.width);
    
                // writing cropped image to disk
                
                logger.info("Path to write cropped image "+ tempDirectoryPath);
                
                String writePath = tempDirectoryPath + "/croppedImg.png";
                logger.info("writepath"+writePath);
                // imagepath = imagepath.
                Imgcodecs.imwrite(writePath, croppedImage);
    
                try {
                    // extracting text from cropped image, goes to the image, extracts text and adds
                    // them to stringBuffer
                    
                    logger.info("Exact Path where Image was written with Name "+ writePath);
                    String textExtracted = (tesseract
                            .doOCR(new File(writePath)));
                    
                    //Adding Seperator
                    textExtracted = textExtracted + "_SEPERATOR_";
                    
                    logger.info("Text Extracted "+textExtracted);
                    
                    textExtracted = textExtracted + "\n";
                    text = textExtracted + text;
                    
                    logger.info("Text Extracted Completely"+text);
                    // System.out.println("Andar Ka Text => " + text.toString());
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    logger.error(exception);
                }
                
                writePath = "";
                logger.info("Making write Path empty for next Image "+ writePath);
            }
    
            }
            catch(CvException ae)
            {
                logger.error("cv",ae);
            }
            catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError ae)
            {
                logger.error("unsatdif",ae);
            }
            catch(Exception ae)
            {
                logger.error("general",ae);
            }
            // converting into string
            return text.toUpperCase();      
            
        }
    
        // convert Mat to Image for GUI output
        public static Image toBufferedImage(Mat m) {
            // getting BYTE_GRAY formed image
            int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
            if (m.channels() > 1) {
                type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
            }
    
            int bufferSize = m.channels() * m.cols() * m.rows();
            byte[] b = new byte[bufferSize];
    
            m.get(0, 0, b); // get all the pixels
    
            // creating buffered Image
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(m.cols(), m.rows(), type);
            final byte[] targetPixels = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
            System.arraycopy(b, 0, targetPixels, 0, b.length);
    
            // returning Image
            return image;
        }
    
        // method to display Mat format images using the GUI
        private static void showWaitDestroy(String winname, Mat img) {
            HighGui.imshow(winname, img);
            HighGui.moveWindow(winname, 500, 0);
            HighGui.waitKey(0);
            HighGui.destroyWindow(winname);
        }
    }
```